# Get GPS coordinates in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to get GPS coordinates in Ionic but I am not being succesful. I am trying to show them in the console but they never show up. This is my first time working with Ionic so I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

/**
 * Generated class for the GpstestPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-gpstest',
  templateUrl: 'gpstest.html',
})
export class GpstestPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private geolocation: Geolocation) {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      let userLocations = {
        lat: resp.coords.latitude,
        lon: resp.coords.longitude
      }
    console.log("Locations acquired");
    console.log(userLocations);
    // resp.coords.latitude
    // resp.coords.longitude
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your native calls in `this.platform.ready()`. That way, cordova will be ready before trying to access native plugins.

As an aside, the Geolocation plugin is also a little finicky and frequently does not work, so that could also be your issue.